# Does a cookie have to be set in the http header?

Tags: html, http, cookies, http-headers

Would like to set cookies from the server (CGI - C)
Can it be set after the header has been printed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, cookies that come directly from the server must be explicitly set in the response header using `Set-Cookie`. See [here](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: how do you do this "indirectly" ?

Comment: By "indirectly", I mean all forms of setting a cookie without the HTTP header. For example on the client side, like David Dorward already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookies using JavaScript embedded in an HTML document, or via a few other mechanisms, such as Flash.

Other than that though, the header is the only place in HTTP you can set them.

Comment: Note that setting cookies in the header and using the HTTPOnly flag is helpful for security - it prevents JavaScript code from reading the cookie, which can stop XSS attacks from hijacking the user's session by stealing their cookies. See http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly and the slightly dated http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html